# transform vector<Foo> to a vector<double> and find the minimum

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, std

I have a `vector<Foo>` and some function `double toDouble(const Foo& foo)`, and I want to find the minimum double value after running the toDouble function over all of the Foos in the vector.

It's an easy enough problem to solve using a for loop, but out of curiosity, is there a slick way to do this using the standard library algorithms?

One idea was to use `std::transform` to convert the `vector<Foo>` to a `vector<double>`  and then use `std::min_element` to find the smallest double value, but that requires filling up a new temporary vector... Is there a more direct solution?

Comment: does this need to be fast? if not, don't worry about the temporary vector, it's a perfectly reasonable solution.

Comment: This question is asked out of curiosity rather than practicality... It's not performance critical code perse, so agreed, the temp vector is not a big deal... I'm just wondering if there is a better solution offered by the standard... (I'll probably just use a for loop anyways.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could abuse [`std::accumulate`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate):

```
vector<Foo> v = ...;

double min = std::accumulate(std::begin(v), std::end(v),
                             std::numeric_limits<double>::max(),
                             [](double so_far, Foo const& next) {
                                 return std::min(so_far, toDouble(next));
                             });
```

Or even, without `numeric_limits`, if you know `v` is non-empty:

```
double min = std::accumulate(std::next(std::begin(v)), std::end(v),
                             toDouble(v[0]),
                             [](double so_far, Foo const& next) {
                                 return std::min(so_far, toDouble(next));
                             });
```

Comment: I don't think it's abusive at all; perfectly normal use of the left fold.

Comment: That's the kind of example I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: Is there a way to also compute at which index the minimum is located?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a min version which takes a comparator and call toDouble within this comparator.

Comment: The issue there is that the result is a Foo iterator. I'd have to convert that Foo back to a double to get my final answer. (totally valid, just looking for something more direct).